# Boot Manager shows 16 (Ubuntu+HDD ) choices to boot

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, uefi, budgie

I'm using Ubuntu Budgie 18.04 on a [HP Pavilion G6](http://www.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c02770249.pdf) with secure boot enabled.

When I try to install Xubuntu, the Boot Manager menu shows 16 Ubuntu entries although I use one operating system, and doesn't show the Xubuntu installation media

[image]

I had this problem before with Ubuntu 18.04 .
so I thought staying away from the HWE kernel and sticking with the GA kernel solved it, but now that workaround failed.  I tried to stay away from HWE because I noticed that with every kernel upgrade a new boot entry showed up in the boot option menus so I thought sticking with GA kernel will fix the problem but it failed .

I used to boot Open SUSE Leap with secure boot enabled, and didn't encounter this problem.

So what should I do?

Comment: Those look like UEFI boot entries, which UEFI saves. You can use efibootmgr to remove those entries, or should be able to remove directly from UEFI boot tab, not UEFI boot menu. See examples of `sudo efibootmgr -b XXXX -B` command (also `man efibootmgr`): https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2289179&p=13331743#post13331743

Comment: @oldfred Thank you so much .

Comment: @oldfred I removed all duplicated entries but with every reboot the computer add a new Ubuntu entry In.  /EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi.   Although the main Ubuntu is  entry in    EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi

Comment: Did you also remove the ubuntu folder in the ESP. Every UEFI install puts a unique folder into the ESP. It should be /EFI/ubuntu. Do not delete /EFI/Microsoft or any other entry you want to keep. Usually UEFI finds Windows, but does not find Ubuntu. Or is it /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi which is the fallback or hard drive boot entry? That originally is a copy of Windows boot file. But grub installs a copy of shimx64.efi as bootx64.efi. A few UEFI default boot the hard drive entry.